# In Feyncalc what is the purpose of DiracChainEvalSign and why does FCFAconvert fail if it is present?

Tags: feyncalc

I have run into this issue and I am not sure how to proceed, I cannot find where DiracChainEvalSign enters into diracObjectsEval which triggers the error in the library source code (see [here](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/blob/a8ef6bfcab4d14ae980936313c5deeb910ee84b8/FeynCalc/Feynman/FCFADiracChainJoin.m#L134)). Any pointers would be much appreciated!

For context this is my code with the .gen and .mod files attached (FeynCalc with Feynarts was loaded before this snippet):

```
tops = CreateTopologies[0, 1 -> 3]
procs = InsertFields[tops, S[1] -> {F[2, {1}], -F[2, {1}], V[1]}, 
  Model -> "SMEFT_d6_UFO_FULL", GenericModel -> "SMEFT_d6_UFO_FULL"]
Paint[procs]

amp[0] = 
 FCFAConvert[CreateFeynAmp[procs], IncomingMomenta -> {pH}, 
  OutgoingMomenta -> {p1, p2, k}, List -> False, ChangeDimension -> 4,
   TransversePolarizationVectors -> {k}, DropSumOver -> True, 
  SMP -> True, Contract -> True, UndoChiralSplittings -> True]
```

[SMEFT_d6_UFO_FULL.gen.txt](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/files/14241307/SMEFT_d6_UFO_FULL.gen.txt)
[SMEFT_d6_UFO_FULL.mod.txt](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/files/14241309/SMEFT_d6_UFO_FULL.mod.txt)

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: The error I get is:
`FCFADiracChainJoin has encountered a fatal problem and must abort the computation. The problem reads: Evaluation of isolated objects failed.`